# Isn't Char IComparable?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, sorteddictionary

When I code in C#, I use`System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary<char,int>` in my code.
But when I call its `Max()` method, it throw a exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: At least one object must implement IComparable.

Doesn't `Char` implement `IComparable`? How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Ps: My code is easy:

```
SortedDictionary<char,int> letter = new SortedDictionary<char,int>;
//some codes
    if (letter.Count != 0) var First = letter.Max();
```

Comment: How exactly are you calling `Max()`?

Comment: Well obviously [it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/system.char.aspx). The problem is in the way you've written your code -- ergo: show your code.

Comment: `var c=new[]{'a','b'}; c.Max();` works fine.

Comment: direct test `Char ch = 'A'; Boolean result = ch is IComparable;` returns `true`

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I have updated my question and added my code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot var First = dictionary.Max(); Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Max()` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>`, and `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

The problem is `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` isn't `IComparable`.

If you want the max key you can use `Keys` property:

```
SortedDictionary<char, int> dict = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
...

var key = dict.Keys.Max();
var value = dict[key];
```

**EDIT:**

If you want count how many times an char is repeated dont use a `SortedDictionary<TKey, Value>`, each element added to the collection requires **O(log n)**. At the end, adding process will take **O(n log n)** operations.

In your case a simple `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` or an array is more suitable:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

foreach (char c in chars)
{
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(c))
        dict[c] = 0;

    dict[c]++;
}

var maxValue = dict.Values.Max();
var keyValues = dict.Where(kv => kv.Value == maxValue);
```

In above code, you find the max count and then the characters with that value.

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I want to get the pair which has the max value. How can I do it?

Comment: @黄煜恒: SortedDictionary is sorted by keys, and actually the best way to get the maximum or minimum is using `Last()` or `First()` since the collection is already sorted. but if you want get the pair by maximum value you can do it using dict.Values: `var value = dict.Values.Max();` and the key: var key = `dict.Keys.First(k => dict[k] == value);` but if this is what you want then use use the dictionary like `SortedDictionary<int, char>` using your actual values as the keys

Comment: My purpose is to count how many times (using `int`) that a specific `char` are there in a passage. So there may be many same `int` if I use `int` as key, I think keys can't be duplicated in a `SortedDictionary<int, char>`. Or can you tell me other data structure which is more appropriate in my case?

Comment: @黄煜恒: updated answer

Comment: I'm supposed to support utf-8, so I think `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is better for me. But I can't understand the difference between `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`. Why `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is more suitable?

Comment: @YuhengHuang: Main difference in your case is efficiency. Since actually you dont need any order in your collection, just the maximum value (even not in the keys) at the end, there is no reason to use a SortedDictionary. The result will be the same, but a SortedDictionary requires more operations to keep the collection sorted. In a Dictionary adding and retrieving operations are closely to O(1) in comparison with a SortedDictionary that requires O(log n) in both operations. If you dont need any order in your keys simply use a Dictionary, will be more efficient.